# Mockito.spy not changing real object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Calling method on spy object somehow has no effect on real spied object:

```
public class AAA {
    public int a;

    public void setA(int aa) {
        this.a = aa;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}


public class Proof {
    @Test
    public void wtf() {
        AAA obj = new AAA();
        AAA spy = Mockito.spy(obj);

        spy.setA(22);

        assertThat(obj.getA(), equalTo(22));
    }
}
```

How can that be? I suppose `Proof` test should pass.

Comment: This looks like intended behaviour? I'm not too familiar with Mockito and spying but from the documentation I see the `wtf` test case should not pass. You are asserting on the `obj` instead of `spy`.

Comment: But is it actually possible to make the spy a "wrapper" around the original object? Say you only want to intercept and count/verify calls and you cannot replace the original reference everywhere. Maybe you are only interested in the interactions of with a single object, but not others. Is this possible with Mockito?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen in the Mockito [doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)):

> Mockito *does not* delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it.

This means that the original object `obj` isn't modify with what happens in the spied object `spy`.

Comment: Right, but also if you change the real-object the spy remains unchanged (they are two separate objects the moment spy returns).

Comment: But is it actually possible to make the spy a "wrapper" around the original object? Say you only want to intercept and count/verify calls and you cannot replace the original reference everywhere. Maybe you are only interested in the interactions of with a single object, but not others. Is this possible with Mockito? How to instruct Mockito to _delegate_ to the real instance?

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests and you should make the assert on spy not an obj:

```
@Test
    public void wtf() {
        AAA obj = new AAA();
        AAA spy = Mockito.spy(obj);

        spy.setA(22);

        assertThat(spy.getA(), equalTo(22));
    }
```